# Null reference error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" accessing Model while loading a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
@model IEnumerable<SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product>.....this is my view List.cshtml

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}
@foreach (var j in Model) //getting error at Model
{ 
    <div class="item">
        <h3>@j.Name</h3>
        @j.Description
        <h4>@j.Price.ToString("C")</h4>
    </div>
}
```

the sportstore example in pro Asp.Net MVC3 book chapter 7 before the part where i can prepare a database

this is my controller

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        public ProductController()
        { 
        }
        //
        // GET: /Product/
        private IProductRepository repository;
        public ProductController(IProductRepository productrepository)
        {
            repository=productrepository;
        }
        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Would you share the index code in the controller?

Comment: I added the error's context to the question title

Comment: Thank you neontapir but how am i supposed to deal with this pls help i am new to ASP.Net MVC

Answer (score 1):

when you pass `IEnumerable` you should pass it as List or something like that, for example your Index Action Method should be like :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(_dbContext.Product.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the Model I suppose, just like we do in C#:
Suppose we have a class, then we initialize the same like:

```
Model m1= new Model();
```

Make sure you check the null also for all items you are passing.

Comment: This is likely the correct explanation. If you use `View()` to return your view, Model is null. You'd want to use the `View(model)` overload to provide a model object.

Comment: @neontapir `@model IEnumerable<SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product>` is `Model` isn't it?

Comment: Yes... but if you don't pass it in the View() call... you end up with a null model.

Comment: Correct, @model defines the type of the model, but not an instance of its current value.

Comment: Yes the error i am getting is that the model is null ..it is not initialized .. i am quite new to ASP.NetMvc pls help guys

Answer (score 0):

In the EFDbContext class i inherited DbConntext and that worked for me, hope it'll help you too:

```
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete
{
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```